# How to resize GWT image generated from servlet?

Tags: java, image, gwt, servlets, image-manipulation

---

I have a servlet that generates PNG using data in database...then in my GWT Application i use the servlet URL to get the image, all of this work perfectly, but the problem is i can't modify the size of image to fit  the box reserved to it since the image is generated from servlet.Is there a method to modify dimensions when generating image? or may be client side solution to setup image's size?
Any ideas how I'd do this?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are loading it in a gwt Image widget. If so, just use the widget functions of `setWidth( "10px")` and `setHeight( "10px")` on the client side.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Note however: If the image is used as a *background* image, then it actually can't be resized on the client (with CSS 2.1)